# How can I see the groovy generated from view templates in Play 1.2.4?

Tags: playframework

I suspect there's a bug in the groovy code that runs in a particular template of mine.

Where can I find it to investigate? I would like to view the Play code that directly runs a template I wrote (using the `%{ code }%` notation), and hopefully debug it.

Comment: Do you have something like a simple isolated piece of your groovy-code that fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Play! code that compiles and renders the templates can be found in this package.

https://github.com/playframework/play/tree/master/framework/src/play/templates

`Template`, `TemplateCompiler` and `BaseTemplate` are abstract, implementation independent classes and **the actual compiling and rendering stuff seem to be done in the classes** `GroovyTemplate` and `GroovyTemplateCompiler`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **Play! does not generate any groovy code**. The template-engine runs your groovy code written in the intended tags. It is similar to a PHP-file, you write html and the **dynamic parts are rendered from your code**.

If you probably meant a bug in the template-tags like `#{form <action>}` or `#{script <path>}` etc., they are not written in Groovy, but in Java. They are called FastTags, because as compiled Java they perform better as template-tags written in Groovy. **You can take a closer look at the implementation of the FastTags on github:**

https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/FastTags.java

If you meant something else, please describe your code and the behavior you recognized as bug more detailed.

Comment: Thanks, I added some clarification to the question.